# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Collapsed for Mobile on Page Load (Laravel/laravel-mix)

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-mix

Well I'm not really sure to turn at this point because this makes absolutely no sense to me.

I'm using the latest version of Laravel and Laravel Mix, which may or may not be related.

I've updated Laravel to use the latest Bootstrap 4 Alpha with the following dependencies:

```
"axios": "^0.16.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
"cross-env": "^5.0.1",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"laravel-mix": "^1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"vue": "^2.1.10",
"tether": "^1.4.0",
"popper.js": "^1.11.0"
```

Everything here is the correct versions.

I've updated my bootstrap.js to include the correct bootstrap module and the newly required modules:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    window.Tether = require('tether');
    window.Popper  = require('popper.js').default;
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

I'v also corrected the SCSS path in app.scss:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Now the problem is that when I load the the app after running `npm run dev` the navbar is collapsed... as if it was on mobile, but I'm testing on a desktop.

Now it gets even weirder because if I include bootstrap.min.css from the Bootstrap CDN, then it works fine.

I don't want to do that though, but clearly I may end up having to because I have no idea what the problem is.

I've tried various things such as commenting out all my custom CSS, Javascript, reinstalling node_modules multiple times, etc. I'm lost at this point.

edit: I've also tried using the default Bootstrap navbar when using my app.css file and it still doesn't work. Again, works fine though if I use the CDN instead.

Comment: Are you able to post the HTML you are using for your navbar? And if you remove the try-catch around your javascript, does it throw any errors?

Comment: @JamesFerguson I've actually tried with the sample Navbar from [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/), deleted all the other HTML, commented out extra CSS/JS files and it still doesn't work. e: Removed the try/catch and still no errors thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jake, my guess is you're getting `bootstrap4.0.0-beta` and trying to use markup and classes related to `bootstrap4.0.0-alpha.6`.

If you uninstall bootstrap and run npm install `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6--save --save-exact`, your code should work.

OR

You can use this code for your navbar in you current project to see if it works correctly.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow, this makes so much sense... Although I find it incredibly stupid that there's not a giant warning that you're reading the alpha docs considering the breaking changes. I've been trying to solve this for hours now. Thank you so much! (I ended up keeping the beta install and using the correct docs)

Comment: I completely agree. The same thing happened to me. Here's the take away though... Read up on [semvar](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) as it relates to npm and your `package.json` file. The `^` symbol in font of your dependency version means it takes the latest package release in that major version (version 4 in this case). Unless you knew that, you'd be beating your head against your desk, not understanding what the hell is going on (like me last week).